# Python Regex to get string(extension) after special character

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I have a string want to get string after special character which is extension.
i tried and it is works fine in javascript but wasnt in python.. how to do that?

here is my JS snippet,

```js
my_str_0 = ".exr[6,7]";
my_str_1 = "/home/mohideen/test_dir/Samp_8860-fg_paint_%04d.exr[6] 1-7";
my_str_2 = "/home/mohideen/test_dir/Samp_8860-fg_paint_%05d.png[1] 1-10";
my_str_3 = "/home/mohideen/test_dir/Samp_8860-fg_paint_%05d.jpg";
for (var i in [my_str_0, my_str_1, my_str_2, my_str_3]) {
 var reg = /([^.]*)$/.exec(eval("my_str_"+i));
 console.log(reg[0]);
}
```

here is my python [regex link](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%5B%5E.%5D*)%24&test_string=%2Fhome%2Fmohideen%2Ftest_dir%2FSAMP_8860-fg_paint_%25d.exr%5B6%5D%201-7%0A%2Fhome%2Fmohideen%2Ftest_dir%2FSAMP_8860-fg_paint_%2504d.exr%5B6%5D%201-7%0A%2Fhome%2Fmohideen%2Ftest_dir%2FSAMP_8860-fg_paint_%2505d.png%5B7%5D%201-10%0A%2Fhome%2Fmohideen%2Ftest_dir%2FSAMP_8860-fg_paint_%2505d.jpg%0A%2504d%0A%27.exr%5B6%2C7%5D%27%0A%27%5B1-7%5D%27&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: [switch on the multiline flag](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%5B%5E.%5D*)%24&test_string=%2Fhome%2Fmohideen%2Ftest_dir%2FSAMP_8860-fg_paint_%25d.exr%5B6%5D%201-7%0A%2Fhome%2Fmohideen%2Ftest_dir%2FSAMP_8860-fg_paint_%2504d.exr%5B6%5D%201-7%0A%2Fhome%2Fmohideen%2Ftest_dir%2FSAMP_8860-fg_paint_%2505d.png%5B7%5D%201-10%0A%2Fhome%2Fmohideen%2Ftest_dir%2FSAMP_8860-fg_paint_%2505d.jpg%0A%2504d%0A%27.exr%5B6%2C7%5D%27%0A%27%5B1-7%5D%27&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: Not clear what output should be.

Comment: i said extension.. after special character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MultiLine Flag.

[See here in this link](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%5B%5E.%5D*)%24&test_string=%2Fhome%2Fmohideen%2Ftest_dir%2FSAMP_8860-fg_paint_%25d.exr%5B6%5D%201-7%0A%2Fhome%2Fmohideen%2Ftest_dir%2FSAMP_8860-fg_paint_%2504d.exr%5B6%5D%201-7%0A%2Fhome%2Fmohideen%2Ftest_dir%2FSAMP_8860-fg_paint_%2505d.png%5B7%5D%201-10%0A%2Fhome%2Fmohideen%2Ftest_dir%2FSAMP_8860-fg_paint_%2505d.jpg%0A%2504d%0A%27.exr%5B6%2C7%5D%27%0A%27%5B1-7%5D%27&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: you're saviour i dont think how i forgot this simple multi line thanks @vks...

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed ur welcome :)